# Problema na execução de um programa em Python com classes

Tags: python

Crie uma classe empregado, com os seguintes atributos:

- numero
- nome
- salBruto
- salLiquido
- taxaIRS
- taxas

E os seguintes métodos:

- calcIRS()
- calcSS()
- calcSalLiquido()

Levando em consideração as seguintes condições:

- Se salário bruto >= 2000.00, taxa irs = 25%
- Se salário bruto >= 1000.00 && < 2000.00, taxa irs = 20%
- Se salário bruto < 1000.00, taxa irs = 17.5%
- SS = taxa fixa de 11%

Crie um objeto a partir desta classe, leia um salário bruto digitado e apresente
no ecrã todos os cálculos pretendidos (Bruto, IRS, SS e Líquido).

```
class empregado:
    def __init__(self, numero, nome, salBruto, salLiquido, taxaIRS, taxas):
        self.numero = numero
        self.nome = nome
        self.salBruto = salBruto
        self.salLiquido = salLiquido
        self.taxaIRS = taxaIRS
        self.taxas = taxas

    def calcIRS(self):
        if (self.salBruto >= 2000):
            self.taxaIRS = self.salBruto * 0.25
        elif ((self.salBruto >= 1000) and (self.salBruto < 2000)):
            self.taxaIRS = self.salBruto * 0.20
        elif (self.salBruto < 1000):
            self.taxaIRS = self.salBruto * 0.175
        return self.taxaIRS

    def calcSS(self):
        self.taxas = self.salBruto * 0.11
        return self.taxas

    def calcSalLiquido(self):
        self.salLiquido = self.salBruto - (self.taxaIRS + self.taxas)
        return self.salLiquido



numero = int(input('Digite o numero do empregado: '))

nome = input('Digite o nome do empregado: ')

salBruto = float(input('Digite o seu salário bruto: '))

taxaIRS = empregado.calcIRS(self=salBruto)

taxas = empregado.calcSS(self=salBruto)

salLiquido = empregado.calcSalLiquido(self=salBruto)

empregado1 = empregado(numero, nome, salBruto, salLiquido, taxaIRS, taxas)



print('Dados Salário do empregado', empregado1.nome, ', nº ', empregado1.numero, ': ')
print('Salário Bruto: ', empregado1.salBruto)
print('Valor do IRS: ', empregado1.taxaIRS())
print('Valor da SS: ', empregado1.taxas())
print('Salário Líquido: ', empregado1.salLiquido())
```

Este erro aparece quando executo o programa e chega a parte de calcular o IRS "**'float' object has no attribute 'salBruto'**".

Alguem me poderia ajudar por favor!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código está errado. Explico com comentários abaixo:

```
# as três linhas seguintes chamam métodos da classe antes de criar a instância
taxaIRS = empregado.calcIRS(self=salBruto)

taxas = empregado.calcSS(self=salBruto)

salLiquido = empregado.calcSalLiquido(self=salBruto)

## cria uma instância de empregado só agora com parametros de construtor 
## calculados pela própria classe
empregado1 = empregado(numero, nome, salBruto, salLiquido, taxaIRS, taxas)
```

Uma forma de corrigir isso seria assim:

```
# cria uma instância de empregado usando um construtor que recebe
# os dados de entrada
empregado1 = empregado(numero, nome, salBruto)

# calcula o que precisa ser calculado usando a instância empregado1
taxaIRS = empregado1.calcIRS()

taxas = empregado1.calcSS()

salLiquido = empregado1.calcSalLiquido()
```

Dê uma estudada sobre como funciona a criação e o uso de classes em python. Aqui tem uma boa referẽncia: http://pythonclub.com.br/introducao-classes-metodos-python-basico.html

Comment: Eu fiz o que voce me disse mas quando eu crio a instancia de empregado usando um construtor que recebe os  dados de entrada dá erro pois faltam os outros 3 argumentos "salLiquido, taxaIRS e taxas" pois tou usando apenas os 3 primeiros

Comment: Você precisa alterar seu construtor original para receber apenas 3 parâmetros.